# Gradle Liquibase plugin not using specified contexts

Tags: gradle, liquibase

We have a Gradle project which uses Liquibase, and our build file has:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.1.1'
        classpath 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'liquibase'
```

Yet when we try to update our project via:

```
gradle update -Dliquibase.contexts=foobar
```

(tried with `--contexts` too)
it seems to ignore the specified contexts and runs all the changesets instead.

Example:

```
changeSet(author: 'me', id: 'someId1', context: 'somethingElse') { // This runs, but shouldn't
// ... 
changeSet(author: 'me', id: 'someId2', context: 'foobar') { // Should only run this
```

The project was forked at one point, so maybe we're misinterpreting the documentation ([original](https://github.com/tlberglund/groovy-liquibase), [new](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-groovy-dsl)) but it seems like this should work.

Do we need a different plugin/version?  Are we calling it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derp, looks like you need to grab the contexts manually in your build file:

```
main {
    if (project.hasProperty('contexts')) {
        contexts contexts
    }
    url 'someurl'
    username 'username'
    password 'pass'
}
```

Then pass it in via:

```
gradle update -Pcontexts=schema
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define your contexts inside task

```
task('liquibase_dev') << {

liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            changeLogFile changeLog
            url 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test'
            username 'postgres'
            password 'admin'
            contexts 'DEV'
        }
    }
}
```

}

Liquibase changelog:

```
<changeSet author="xxx" context="DEV" id="1591257804177-1" ...>
<changeSet author="xxx" context="PROD" id="1591257804177-2" ...>
```

Then you can run like:

```
./gradlew :liquibase_dev update
```

Only the first changeset will be executed

Answer (score 0):

Newer plugin (2.0.3), same problem and slightly different solution, 'cause I'm keeping a default context.

liquibase.gradle (snippet):

```
if (!project.hasProperty("contexts")) {
    project.ext.contexts = "dev"
}

liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            driver "${datasource_driver}"
            url "${datasource_url}"
            username "${datasource_username}"
            password "${datasource_password}"
            changeLogFile "src/main/resources/db/changelog/master.xml"
            defaultSchemaName ""
            logLevel "info"
            contexts contexts
        }
    }
}

tasks.liquibaseUpdate.dependsOn(tasks.classes)
```

gradle.properties (snippet):

```
liquibaseTaskPrefix=liquibase
```

So, now it's safe to call:

```
./gradlew liquibaseUpdate # to apply contexts=dev
```

And:

```
./gradlew liquibaseUpdate -Pcontexts=test # to apply contexts=test
```